# Problem starting a new JRuby ScriptingContainer and setting Output & Error PrintStreams

Tags: jruby

I am embedding JRuby using Red Bridge into an app and seem to have problems setting out and err. My tests use a `PrintStream` that writes to a `StringBuilder`, after doing some stuff with the JRuby, I then check the stuff printed to out with `puts`. The problem is only the first `setOutput` works everyting gets printed to that.

The simple sample below demonstrates the problem. It is using `PrintStream`s that write to different files to demonstrate the problem. Looking at your file system will show that everything goes to the first "file" when one would expect files 2 and 3 to also be written.

```
package XXX.jruby;

import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.jruby.embed.LocalContextScope;
import org.jruby.embed.LocalVariableBehavior;
import org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer;

public class JRubyShellPutsProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            final ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer(LocalContextScope.CONCURRENT, LocalVariableBehavior.PERSISTENT);
            // container.resetWriter();
            // container.resetErrorWriter();

            final PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream("d:\\out" + i + ".txt");
            container.setOutput(printStream);
            container.setError(printStream);

            container.runScriptlet("puts \"hello" + i + "\"\n");
            printStream.flush();
            container.terminate();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried `ScriptingContainer.resetWriter` but that does not work as one would expect. Sometimes stuff gets written to files 1 and 2 but nothing to 3.

Comment: @Mark final is a marker affecting the ability of my loop to change the value of the local. JRuby does not know or care about this local variable and thus this is a non issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed LocalContextScope to THREADSAFE from CONCURRENT and this seemed to fix the problem.